# How to remove second boot OS to install another OS?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I have a laptop with dual boot with Windows10 installed first and then Linux Mint and at boot appears the Grub menu.

I'd like to install another Linux distro, but first I'd like to remove the Linux Mint installation, so what should be the correct way to proceed in order to avoid boot issues with Windows10 later?

sd6, sda7 and sda8 belongs to Linux Mint.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to remove an entry from the Grub menu.
Since you will be running it from Linux Mint, you won't be able to boot again into it
after you execute the following procedure, so I suggest preparing and testing
a boot media for your new Linux distribution before starting.

This is the procedure for Ubuntu and Linux Mint:

- Install Grub Customizer: `sudo apt install grub-customizer`
- Launch the Grub Customizer application
- Click the "List configuration" tab to load up the Grub menu found on your Linux PC
- Right-click the Linux Mint entry
- In the right-click menu select Remove
- Click the "Save" button
- Update Grub by: `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot and install the new Linux, deleting or formatting the partition(s)
  taken up by the old installation.

For more information and other Linux distributions, see the article
[How to remove broken Grub boot entries on Linux](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/remove-broken-grub-boot-entries-on-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case If I don't install inmeadiately the other Linux distro, will I be able to boot in Windows?

Comment: As long as the Windows 10 entry stays in Grub, it should be OK. If worried, you could also have available a Windows installation media.

Comment: I undertand. And with the procedure you shared, Windows entry will be there, and after install the other Linux Distro, I'll need to update grub again in order grub menu shows new Linux entry or automatically should appear after installation?

Comment: Most Linux installations automatically update Grub. In case of a problem use the [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/).